Jackson parse json to Map<String,Object> with nested fields proper parsing of nested field to Map
I have a json like the following:
{
  "id": "uuid-1111"
  "country": "US",
  "car_brand": "Ford",
  "info": {
    "color": "red",
    "weight": 70
  }
}

I have a Data class:
public class Data implements Serializable {

    private Map<String, Object> jsonData;

    public Map<String, Object> getJsonData() {
        return jsonData;
    }

    public void setJsonData(Map<String, Object> jsonData) {
        this.jsonData = jsonData;
    }
}

I parse the json string to a Map<String,Object> with jackson using:
HashMap<String, Object> props = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>() {
                });
// assign it to the jsonData attribute:
Data data = new Data();
data.setJsonData(props);

after that I wanted to access the "info" field of the json (map) and also parse it to a Map<String,Object> like this:
String infoJson = data().getJsonData().get("info").toString();
HashMap<String, Object> props2 = new ObjectMapper().readValue(infoJson, new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>() {});

but this throws JsonProcessingException with message: Unexpected character ('c' (code 99)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
And that is correct because when I log infoJson it looks like (notice it does not have double quotes, belive this happened because it was already mapped earlier) {color=red, weight=70}
So I tried to directly cast to map and it worked:
HashMap<String, Object> props = (HashMap<String, Object>) data.getJsonData().get("info");
but maybe there is another way safer with jackson instead of directly casting, if there is not, how can I make sure I can cast it before trying so I avoid exception? Thanks!

Presumably that cast is giving you a compiler warning ... 'cos that is an unchecked cast as far as the type parameters are concerned.

@StephenC Yes, im trying to find a way to validate or make sure it is casteable before casting, just to avoid this warning or errors, I could not find a way to do the parsing with jackson

You missed my point.  There isn't a way to do that because the type HashMap<String, Object> is not available for testing at runtime.  The runtime type is just HashMap.  You will (only) get an exception if the returned object is not a HashMap.  The result type of get is Object.

But ... hey ... what is wrong with catching the exception or even letting it propagate?  If you get something that the Jackson can't convert to a HashMap ... that is an exceptional event.  You are certainly going to need to do some sort of recovery at some level ... even if that is just to log the exceptional event and bail out.

@StephenC True, I guess I will go with catching the exception in case it happens, also I have a question about the initial jackson parsing im doing because the direct cast from Object to Hashmap is working, but does that means that when the initial parsing happened, jackson did parse to Hashmap properly the "value" of the "info" field of the json? despite parsing to Hashmap<String,Object>? That is why it no longer has double quotes to be able to parse it a second time via jackson
